# React Not Updating Component?

Tags: reactjs, google-maps

Im struggling to understand why my `<MapWrap>` component is not updating with new information. I have the following set up:

```
const ExternalList = ({ externalData }) => {
    return( 
        <div>
        {externalData.map(({data, meta, idx}) => (
          <div key={idx}>
            {data!= undefined ? <ExternalCardElement key={idx} raw={data} meta={meta}   /> : <></>}
          </div>  
        ))}
      </div>
    );     
}

  const Feed = ({internalData, setMarkerData, externalData}) => {
    useEffect(() => {
      let tmpArr = [];
      internalRaw.docs.forEach((element) => {
        tmpArr.push({ 
          position: {
            lng: parseFloat(element.data().longitude),
            lat: parseFloat(element.data().latitude),
          },
       
        });
      });
      externalData.forEach(({ element }) => {
        if (element) {
          tmpArr.push({
            position: {
              lng: parseFloat(element.longitude),
              lat: parseFloat(element.latitude),
            },
          });
        } 
      });
      setMarkerData(tmpArr);
    }, [internalData, externalData]);
    return(
      <>
      <div>
        { internalData.docs.length > 0 ? (internalData.docs.map((tmp,idx) =><InternalCardElement key={idx} id={tmp.id} raw={tmp.data()} />)) : ( <></> )}
      </div>
      <InviteList externalData={externalData} />
      </>
    )
  }
  const FeedWraper = ({setMarkerData, internalData, externalRaw}) => {   
    const externalData = externalRaw.docs.map(curEle => {
      const [ data, loading, error ] = useDocumentData(curEle.data().ref);
      const meta = curEle;
      return { data, element,loading };
      }); 
      return(
        <>
        {!externalData.loading ?
          <Feed internalData={internalData} externalData={externalData} setMarkerData={setMarkerData} /> 
        :<></>}
        </>
      )
  }

export default function Dashboard() {
  const [markerData,setMarkerData] = useState([])
  const [internalData, internalLoading, error] = useCollection(ineternalQuery);
  const [externalRaw, externalRawLoading, baderror] = useCollection(externalQuery);
  return (
    <div>
    <div>
        {!internalLoading && !externalRawLoading ?
        <FeedWraper internalData={internalData} externalRaw={externalRaw} setMarkerData={setMarkerData}/>
        :<></>}
    </div>
    <div>
    <MapWrap  markerData={markerData} defaultLocation={false} />  
    </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

This creates an infinite rerender but I'm not sure why since the dependencies array of the useEffect() does not change.

Ive tried, without useEffect() and without useState(). I either have an ininite loop of renders or the changes to the marker array does not trigger a rerender.

Comment: Define markerData with useState

Comment: @HimuraDaBattosuai I tried, I'm not passing markerData to components and only passing setMarkerData as useState(). Now it rerenders infinitely

Comment: If you update with setMarkerData, which triggers a re render. If any dependent component also use setMarkerData, then it will also re render. Which can cause a infinite rerender. It must be used with markerData as useState value.

Comment: @HimuraDaBattosuai I appended sudo code for how I implemented what I think you are telling me.

Comment: Commented in an answer, as its too long

Comment: @HimuraDaBattosuai I updated the code. I appreciate the help and apologize for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

First, not sure this works, `<FeedWrapper (setMarkers)>`. It should be `<FeedWrapper setMarkers={setMarkers}>`

Lets go by what I am finding problems with your code.
With `FeedWrapper` you have Feed as child, which has `InternalList` and `ExternalList` as children.
You have sent `setMarkers` in `FeedWrapper`. But in component `const FeedWraper = ({markerData}) => {` .
Here you should have only `setMarkers` as that is the props you send. And you should have send like this, `<FeedWrapper setMarkers={setMarkers}>`
Also you provided children such as `Feed`. But in `FeedWrapper` component you used `Feed` Component again. If you could create a sample code snippet in code snadbox. I might help you with that. Because, in code example, it seems to many react basic mistake.

Answer (score 0):

It was because I had an improper check of a loading variable in the `<FeedWrapper/>` component. Altering the check to the following code made sure that externalData was actually done loading. Which then allowed me to update state in the child components.

```
 return(
        <>
        {externalData.length == internalData.docs.length ?
        <>
          {externalData.length === 0 || externalData[externalData.length-1].loading === false  ?
          <Feed internalData={internalData} externalData={externalData} setMarkerData={setMarkerData} /> 
          :<></>}
        </>
        :<></>}
        </>
      )
```